# How to get different rate for a date range period in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an ipnut as below

```
code       startdate              enddate                  rate

f2  2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-18 00:00:00.000     12
f2  2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     8

g1  2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-20 00:00:00.000     7
g1  2016-09-21 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     5

jn  2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-15 00:00:00.000     15
jn  2016-09-16 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     10
```

i want output corresponding to each startdate and enddate period, code wise as below using oracle.

```
code       startdate              enddate                  rate

f2  2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-15 00:00:00.000     12
f2  2016-09-16 00:00:00.000 2016-09-18 00:00:00.000     12
f2  2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 2016-09-20 00:00:00.000     8
f2  2016-09-21 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     8

g1  2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-15 00:00:00.000     7
g1  2016-09-16 00:00:00.000 2016-09-18 00:00:00.000     7
g1  2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 2016-09-20 00:00:00.000     7
g1  2016-09-21 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     5

jn  2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-15 00:00:00.000     15
jn  2016-09-16 00:00:00.000 2016-09-18 00:00:00.000     10
jn  2016-09-19 00:00:00.000 2016-09-20 00:00:00.000     10
jn  2016-09-21 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000     10
```

Comment: ? What are the rules that lead from the input you provided to the output you show?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find all the startdate and enddate periods from the given table i.e.:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| STARTDATE | ENDDATE   |
+-----------+-----------+
| 01-SEP-16 | 15-SEP-16 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 16-SEP-16 | 18-SEP-16 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 19-SEP-16 | 20-SEP-16 |
+-----------+-----------+
| 21-SEP-16 | 30-SEP-16 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

And then find rate for each of the above period when the period from the give table fall within the above period.

Try this:

```
select
  t.code,
  t2.startdate,
  t2.enddate,
  t.rate
from t inner join (
  select startdate, min(enddate) enddate
  from (
    select distinct startdate
    from t
  ) t1 inner join (
    select distinct enddate
    from t
  ) t2 on t1.startdate <= t2.enddate
  group by startdate
) t2 on t.startdate <= t2.startdate
and t.enddate >= t2.enddate
order by 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/HMPDF35830)

Comment: What did you assume the requirement to be? (Since it is not visible in the original post, it may help to state exactly what you solved here.)